# Calculation of sum in python

Tags: python, sum

During my classes I was asked to write a programme which would calculate below equation, where d is the distance to the closest integer.

[image: 1]

What I have written so far:

```
def suma(x,y,z):
    d = 0
    f = 0
    if x - math.ceil(x) < math.floor(x) - x:
        d == x - math.ceil(x)
    else:
        d == math.floor(x) - x
    for i in range(y,z):
        k = list(range(y,z))
        f += math.pow(2,k[i])*pow(d,2)*(x/pow(2,k[i]))
    return f

print(suma(6,0,15))
```

The result is giving me 0.0 and I am wondering where I have made a mistake.

I would really your appreciate your support in evaluating below code - I am completely new not only to Python, but also programming, but am eager to learn and looking forward for feedback.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Doing `d == ...` doesn't assign anything to `d`. You mean `d = ...`

Comment: i see you do not assign values to d, because you use == operator

Comment: _"The result is giving me 0.0"_. What result are you supposed to be getting? It's hard to debug this without knowing what a correct answer looks like.

Comment: @ZuzannaNikitorowicz Welcome to Stack Overflow. There's no need to add the code language to the question (in this case Python) - that's all taken care of with tags (which you've added) :)

Comment: Just a math question: why do you have `math.pow(2,k[i])*(1/pow(2,k[i]))` in your equation? That equals to 1. So you are essentially doing `math.pow(d,2)*x`, within the summation ...

Comment: @tobias_k at the beginning of the program I set x as x = rd.uniform(0,100), so that it is not integer

Comment: What is this supposed to calculate in the first place? You posted the formula, but what does the result signify?

Answer (score 2):

By doing `d == x - math.ceil(x)`, you are actually comparing the value of d. You meant to write `d = x - math.ceil(x)`.

That's why this is returning 0 in the end, because the value of d is never updated.

Comment: I agree that this is a problem, but even after changing the `==`s to `=`s, the result is still 0.0. There must be something else going on, too.

Comment: Yeah, by doing `d = math.floor(x) - x`, it will be 0 everytime x is an integer. Same goes for `d = x - math.ceil(x)`

Answer (score 1):

There are some more problems with your code, besides using `==` for the assignments:

- your `d` is *not* the distance to the closest integer; when you put in `x=6.3`, you get `-0.7`, but should get `0.3`. Instead just use `d = x - round(x)`
- your loop with the `range` does not make any sense and only works because `y` is `0`, and thus `k[i]` is the same as `i`; instead, just loop `for k in range(y, z)`

With this, you can simplify/fix your code to this:

```
def suma(x, y, z):
    d = x - round(x)
    f = 0
    for k in range(y, z):
        f += 2**k * d**2 * x/(2.**k)
    return f
```

Or shorter, using `sum` with a generator expression. Also, no need to calculate `d**2` in each iteration of the loop:

```
def suma(x, y, z):
    d2 = (x - round(x))**2
    return sum(2**k * d2 * x/(2.**k) for k in range(y, z))
```

---

Also, as noted in comments, `2**k * d**2 * x/(2.**k)` should be the same as `d**2 * x`, as the two `2**k` cancel each other out, so you can simplify your code further; you do not even need the sum, since the terms are independent from `k` (assuming that your formula is correct as posted).

```
def suma(x, y, z):
    d2 = (x - round(x))**2
    return d2 * x * (z - y)
```

Comment: When `x = 6.8` for instance, `round(x)` gives `7` and `d` would be `-0.2`. Here it doesn't matter since we take the square but in another case this should be taken into account. Just wanted to point out because OP seems to be confused about rounding functions.

Comment: @Motun True; first I had an `abs` in there, but as you say, the number is squared anyway. The problem with OP's approach was that she checks `x - ceil(x)` and `floor(x) - x`, which will both be negatives, and then takes the _smaller_ of those, i.e. the one with the larger _absolute_ value.